# Encoding Error Using AWS S3 Select with the AWS SDK for Ruby

Tags: aws-sdk-ruby, amazon-s3-select

I am trying to do the following:

- download the output of an Athena query from S3 (`file.csv`)
- gzip the output and upload to a different S3 location (`file.csv.gz`)
- use S3 Select from within the Ruby SDK to query the contents of `file.csv.gz`

I always get the following error, always "near byte 8192", even when the contents of `file.csv.gz` are completely different:

`Aws::S3::Errors::InvalidTextEncoding (UTF-8 encoding is required. The text encoding error was found near byte 8,192.)`

NB: using the same S3 Select query against the same, uncompressed `file.csv` works as expected.  I have tried all kinds of weird things but am full of despair.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Start with file `s3://mybucket/file.csv`
2. Download with aws-cli: `aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/file.csv file.csv`
3. Gzip the file: `gzip file.csv`
4. Upload the `file.csv.gz`: `aws s3 cp file.csv.gz s3://mybucket/file.csv.gz`

Here's the code:

```
class RunsS3SelectQueries
  def self.client
    @client ||= Aws::S3::Client.new
  end

  def self.run_query(sql:, bucket:, key:)
    data = ""
    handler = Aws::S3::EventStreams::SelectObjectContentEventStream.new
    handler.on_records_event do |event|
      puts "----records payload:----"
      payload = event.payload.read
      data += payload
    end
    handler.on_stats_event do |event|
       # get :stats event that contains progress information
       puts event.details.inspect
       # => Aws::S3::Types::Stats bytes_scanned=xx, bytes_processed=xx, bytes_returned=xx
    end
    params = {
      bucket: bucket,
      key: key,
      expression_type: "SQL",
      expression: sql,
      input_serialization: {
        csv: { file_header_info: "USE"}
      },
      output_serialization: {
        csv: {}
      },
      event_stream_handler: handler,
    }
    client.select_object_content(params)
    data
  end
end
```

The following receives the text encoding error.

```
output = RunsS3SelectQueries.run_query(sql: %q{SELECT * FROM S3Object }, bucket: 'mybucket', key: 'file.csv.gz')
```

However, running against the uncompressed `file.csv` does not:

```
output = RunsS3SelectQueries.run_query(sql: %q{SELECT * FROM S3Object }, bucket: 'mybucket', key: 'file.csv')
```

I've tried all kinds of combinations of text encodings, content-type metadata, content-encoding, etc., and can't seem to find anything that works.  The fact that it always gets the error on byte 8192 is pretty weird/suspicious, in my opinion.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify that the input is gzipped in `input_serialization`, otherwise s3 will try to decode the gzip header and will get an error about it not being valid utf-8 at byte 8192.

Something like the following will work:

`input_serialization: {
        csv: { file_header_info: "USE"}
        CompressionType: "GZIP"
}`